# Laravel 7 Multiple Form Actions

Tags: php, html, forms, vuejs2, laravel-7

I'm currently working on a little shop I've built in Laravel 7.
The cart of my shop consists of a HTML form containing two submit buttons:

```
<form action="{{ route('edit_cart') }}" method="post">
@csrf

<!-- some more form code here -->

<div>
  <div>
      <input type="image" name="pp_submit" src="/img/shop/checkout-logo-large-de.png">
  </div>
  <div>
      <input type="submit" name="cart_submit" value="ZUR KASSE GEHEN">
  </div>

</form>
```

I want each of the submit buttons to trigger a different action leading to different routes to different controllers.

Can I manage this without using JS?
And if it can only be done with JS - what would be the easiest way do it with VueJS?
Do I need to submit the form via VueJS? Or is there a way to dynamically set the action attribute of the form tag with VueJS?

Thanks for your help,

Lena

Comment: with VueJS you can use @click in each of them and mention function for them which will call different apis/routes but the form validation have to be in function as well